# What happened to the PhyLoTA browser?

Tags: phylogenetics, phylogeny, public-databases

A paper I'm reading from 2021<sup>[1]</sup> mentions doing some analysis on data from the PhyLoTA database, with this reference citation:

- M. J. Sanderson et. al. 2008 [The PhyLoTa Browser: processing GenBank for molecular phylogenetics research](https://doi.org/10.1080/10635150802158688), *Syst. Biol.* 57(3) 335-346.

This paper abstract claims to have an online interface at http://loco.biosci.arizona.edu/pb, but this link is not currently responsive. Does anyone know what happened to this project, and if it is currently accessible at some other location?

---

[1] S. M. Harrington et. al. 2021 [Properties of Markov chain Monte Carlo performance across many empirial alignments](https://doi.org/10.1093/molbev/msaa295) MBE

Answer (score 1):

Phylota was implemented in R and is present on [GitHub here](https://github.com/ropensci/phylotaR), described by [Bennett *et al* (2018)](https://doi.org/10.3390/life8020020).

Here's the code...

```
library(phylotaR)
wd <- '[FILEPATH TO WORKING DIRECTORY]'
ncbi_dr <- '[FILEPATH TO COMPILED BLAST+ TOOLS]'
txid <- 9443  # primates ID
setup(wd = wd, txid = txid, ncbi_dr = ncbi_dr)
run(wd = wd)
```

Sanderson *et al*  was 15 years ago, albeit Sys. Biol. is a very reputable journal in phylogenetics. I've deployed solutions published there with outstanding results.